# Hibernate-sequence generates duplicate keys when using hibernate envers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-envers, database-sequence, mariadb-10.6

I am using hibernate envers 5.6.9.final with spring boot 2.7.2.

**my problem is that hibernate_sequence sometimes generates duplicates value when it needs to insert a new record in revisionInfo tabel. and it only happens on openshift platform and not my local system and not always it fails but sometimes it is running successfully.**

this is how the AuditRivitionEntity is defined:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "revision_info")
@RevisionEntity(AuditRevisionListener.class)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "revision_seq", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence")
@AttributeOverride(name = "timestamp", column = @Column(name = "rev_timestamp"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "revision_id"))
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class AuditRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

  @Column(name = "user")
  private String user;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!super.equals(obj)) {
      return false;
    }
    return user.equals(((AuditRevisionEntity) obj).getUser());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), user);
  }

}
```

the issue is that it is useing hibernate_sequence to generate revision_id but on the server on which the system is deployed sometimes it trys to insert duplicate values for revision_id which are already inserted and used.

how come is it possible that a sequence generates a duplicate key while if I call `SELECT nextval(hibernate_sequence)` manually and it returns correct value.

this is where the entities are persisted and I expect the auditing be persisted as well:

```
  @Transactional
  public void saveNumberDirectoryEntry(NumberDirectoryEntry entry) {
    numberDirectoryEntryRepository.save(entry);
    numberDirectoryEntryUriRepository.saveAll(entry.getUriList());
  }
```

here is the log from hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval(hibernate_sequence)
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,378[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:144[0;39m - 
    insert 
    into
        revision_info
        (rev_timestamp, user, revision_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        revision_info
        (rev_timestamp, user, revision_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,378[0;39m [39mTRACE[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:64[0;39m - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1699974632377]
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,378[0;39m [39mTRACE[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:64[0;39m - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Erpm admin admin]
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,378[0;39m [39mTRACE[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder.bind:64[0;39m - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [2]
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,379[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.m.j.u.l.Slf4JLogger.warn:100[0;39m - Error: 1062-23000: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,380[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:137[0;39m - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,380[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:142[0;39m - (conn=1884477) Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,381[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mo.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl.release:213[0;39m - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,383[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mi.k.e.s.w.n.CreateNumberDirectoryEntryWorker.execute:64[0;39m - Failed to persist number directory entry due to: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
[34m2023-11-14 15:10:32,385[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mTopicSubscriptionManager[0;39m] [33mi.k.e.s.w.n.CreateNumberDirectoryEntryWorker.execute:67[0;39m - Some exception occurred while storing number directory entry: 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
```

I get this error `Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'` while sequence should return 10.

I have tried to change the AuditRevisionEntity and added
`@SequenceGenerator(name = "revision_seq", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence")` and also changes the sequence name but nothing has changes.
Also I change the boarder of transaction, exclude extra code from transaction and made as small as possible. or I removed the cascade strategy on the association of numberDirectoryEntry and Uri and persist the entity and Uri separately, no difference.

I am using Maria db 10.6

Comment: The issue is fixed: as mariadb supports auto-increment id generation. I changed the AuditRevisionEntity to a custom defined entiry and set id generation strategy to Identity and removed hibernate_sequence which for some strange reasons was returning invalid values.

Comment: I tried your advise, but I am getting:

`java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: I have also posted my question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875583/after-spring-hibernate-envers-update-sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception?noredirect=1#comment137319371_77875583

Comment: I solved it by using `@TableGenerator` for `id` field